# TLS Certificate life for IoT System

Tags: tls, iot

I'm developing an IoT product's software, where it runs HTTPS client.

Given that the certificate of servers are renewed every year, it's not that issue while we're authenticating against the Intermediate Certificate (as Let's Encrypt).
Given those certificates have also a lifetime, so **a solution might be to** select a CA which have a long lifetime [Longer than the product lifetime (perhaps ~10 years)].

Given this suggested solution, **what are recommended CAs for meeting this criteria?**

Alternatively, **is it a workable approach to update the stored CA certificate before changing the server's certificate by 3 months of the expiration of both CA and the server's certificates?**

About limitations: could the server hold two different certificates within this update period?